# What is this N-shaped icon on my HTC One?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, htc-one, notification-icons

[image: N-shaped icon]

I have an HTC One with Sprint, and I believe this icon appeared after the 4.3 update.  I have gone through the list of apps (both running and total) but nothing appears to match up.  Other friends with Android phones don't appear to have this icon, but they all root and customize 7893 ways.  Can anybody identify this icon?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means that [you have NFC enabled](http://www.droid-life.com/2012/11/28/that-new-square-like-box-in-your-notification-bar-is-the-nfc-icon/). Some manufacturers (LG and HTC, I know for certain) have started adding an icon to let you know that you have NFC enabled since it can have potential security implications related to mobile payment systems. It would also be useful to know if you intend to use features like Android Beam.

If you'd like to get rid of the icon, you can disable NFC in your settings by selecting "More..." in the Wireless & Networks subheading and then unchecking the "NFC" option (you can view Sprint's official instructions [here](http://support.sprint.com/support/tutorial/Turn_NFC_Near_Field_Communication_on_or_off_HTC_One/47845-1304)).

The icon they're using is the official logo of the [NFC Forum](http://www.nfc-forum.org/home/).

Comment: That indeed was the case with my S4.  Thanks for posting the question and the answer.  Not sure how it was turned-on, but it's been driving me nuts for days.