# Complete list of Lollipop system icons shown in notification bar?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notification-bar, notification-icons

Is there a complete list of these? I've seen lots of Q&A about "What does x icon mean" but it would be really useful if there were a complete list for reference!

Comment: If you know what some of them are, you could answer your own question, and make it a community wiki. Then others could edit it to add to the list and this would be the "complete list for reference". Even linking to the other questions that relate to specific icons.

Comment: This might be a challenge. For the starter, [this is a gallery of Lollipop (Material) drawables provided by Google](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/). Some of them are for icons/buttons/menu, so you may disregard those. The problem is, there is no good indicator whether it's used in Lollipop's system notification or not.

Comment: I'm afraid there won't ever be a "complete list": as soon as it were compiled, some manufacturers already had added their own modifications... No guess, but experience from the past.

Comment: @AndrewT.: And even that doesn't list all icons that appear there, eg. the N-shaped NFC icon that [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55953/what-is-this-n-shaped-icon-on-my-htc-one) talks about. (The link talks about a different version, but I have that icon on Lollipop)

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo Unfortunately, vendors are free to use different icons (Nexus doesn't have that icon), that's why it's difficult to find one for all possible icons.

Answer (score 10):

Google provides [a big, categorized list of Material icons](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) with few-word description.

Note however that *not all of them* are used for system notifications.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for but I found this:

[image: Complete List Icons]

This includes **all material action icons** in Lollipop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's actually a screenshot from a link provided on my comment on the question :) ... though I'm not sure if all of them are notification icons.

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen your comment sorry. I don't know either but this is the most complete list I found.

Comment: Could you provide the source in your answer?

Comment: https://www.techrevolutions.fr/200-icones-gratuites-pour-vos-app-chez-google

Comment: I'm looking for a filled white circle with a transparent minus sign inside...