# Where can I find documentation for icons used in the notification bar?

Tags: notification-icons

My WiFi icon on the notification bar is displaying an exclamation point and triangles (up/down arrows?). When I try to use Google to find what they mean, there's no clear place documenting notification icons.

I eventually found the exclamation point - can't connect to Google services - but the triangles just aren't searchable.

**Where can I find documentation regarding what those sometimes-cryptic notification icons mean?**

Comment: Generally, notification icons can be modified by manufacturers and carriers.  Even though they try to follow some standards (e.g. Wi-Fi icon looks similar everywhere,) they aren't required to do so.  Bottom line - manufacturer's website is usually the best bet to find information on their particular notifications.

Comment: Related: [Complete list of Lollipop system icons shown in notification bar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/98975/44325)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a list [material icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/) linked in [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads) which is as official it can be.

But note that OEMs and carriers are free to add / modify their own icons so it's not possible to have all the icons listed on one site officially.