# Term for decoding symbols / icons

Tags: notification-bar

The top of the phone often has symbols to indicate features such as battery life, cell tower signal strength, wifi strength, etc.

Is there a commonly accepted term for said symbols?  Usually there is a list of symbols and the symbol's meaning.  This list should have a name: what is the name of this list?

The idea is that the term for said list would be found in the phone's manual, when trying to lookup what an unknown symbol communicates.

Comment: Are you looking for say IconA is usually called this, IconB usually called that, etc?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio  Good question: I have tried to clarify the ask

Comment: Maybe kind of related:[Complete list of Lollipop system icons shown in notification bar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98975/complete-list-of-lollipop-system-icons-shown-in-notification-bar)

Comment: The right ones are status bar icons and left ones are called notification bar icons. This is what I have read anywhere. You would have hard luck finding out the meaning of many of those icons because OEMs do not keep their user manual either exhaustive or updated.